# How to follow forks, but detach on exec in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm trying to troubleshoot [a hairy bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue37168) which involves corruption of a particular integer in memory. I can set a watchpoint and hope to capture a backtrace of whatever is changing this particular value.

Complicating matters, the bug only occurs in production, and only a few times per day. And the bug occurs in a Python webserver called gunicorn, which is a pre-fork server. The corruption happens in one of the worker children, not the master process.

Trouble is, gdb by default won't debug children produced by `fork()`. If configured to do so with `set detach-on-fork off`, then it might debug the worker processes, but it will *also* debug other subprocesses if one of the workers does a `fork()` and `exec()`.

So is there a way to configure gdb to:

- debug child processes produced by `fork()`, *and*
- detach from a process when it does `exec()`?

Or perhaps there's some other approach to the issue of debugging the worker children of a pre-fork server?

Comment: Just having read what a 'pre-fork' server means, can you not attach gdb to each of the workers separately after the forks are done during initialization?

Comment: @itisravi technically possible, sure. But how do you orchestrate that over a fleet of 200 servers, each running 400 workers each, with the workers dynamically terminating and restarting all the time? Possibly some kind of process that watches for new workers, but then what if the bug occurs immediately after the fork, before gdb has attached to the worker?